# How can I record an offline contribution with multiple line items?

Tags: contributions, line-items

My use case is a donor who makes a donation that needs to be allocated to multiple funds.  For instance, a check for $20,000, with $10K for general operating expenses and $10K for a special program fund.

While I'm clear how to make an online contribution page that allocates funds to multiple line items, I'm not sure if there's a way to do this from an offline contribution page.

Comment: I thought Price Sets became available for use via backend - but suspect you know that and hence this issue is a layer deeper than that

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Thanks for overestimating me!  I'm not used to thinking of price sets in this way - I suspect Allen's solution will work for me.  Not as flexible as I'd like, but maybe that's for the best.

Comment: nw (no worries). Allen's looked like a good explanation of what i was hinting at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a Price Set for contributions pointing to the multiple funds needed. Each fund should have a price of 1.00.  You could include additional funds besides the two in question so that the Price Set is ready to be used like this in the future for other potential donation splits.
- If the donation needs to be attributed to a certain contribution page, create that contribution page.
- Enter a 'New Contribution' under 'Contributions' menu.
- Once the price set is created, next to the amount field, you should have the option to choose a Price Set.
- Choose your new price set, and split the donation as needed to each fund.
- Enter the check info and other pertinent contribution info.
- Pick Contribution Page under 'Additional Details' if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To my Knowledge - you can use financial type for each line item

Each financial type should have a perentage of allocation of the given fund

For example :

If you have two line item Donation (10%) and member dues (90%) set up in the financial type

If a member makes a payment of 100 pounds then 10 pound is allocated to donation and remaining is been allocated to member dues

I guess this helps!!!